# Is there any way to specify order of alternate questions in QnA pair (QnA Maker)?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am using QnA Maker Service and also active learning feature via [explicit feedback](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot) which works as follows: query QnA Maker, find ambigous questions/answer pairs, create hero card by choosing **first question** from each QnA pair (QnAMakerResult) and send it to the user.

Since I am using this logic I want to have the best looking **first question** in **QnA pair**. But I have found out that when I click on Save and Train in QnA Maker portal, it will override my order of alternate questions in qna pair which completely breaks active learning experience because some questions in qna pair are not so user friendly such as only specific keywords etc.

Is there any way how to mark some alternate question for this purpose (like mark the most user friendly question) or to disable this automatic sorting in QnA Maker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a language, my answer refers to the C# SDK, but the concepts should be transferable to the other SDKs.

I believe you might be able to achieve the functionality that you want in a roundabout and somewhat manual way:

1. In the QnA Maker Portal [add a metadata property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/edit-knowledge-base#add-metadata) to the questions you'd like to disambiguate, it could have the key `disambiguation-question` and the value would be the question you'd like to use for disambiguation. An example is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/add-question-metadata-portal#add-metadata-to-filter-the-answers). e.g. `disambiguation-question`: `My question that I want to use to disambiguate`.
2. Save, Train, and Publish your Knowledge base.
3. Update your code to filter on the [`Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.queryresult.metadata?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_AI_QnA_QueryResult_Metadata)property of the [`QueryResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.queryresult?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) class, which contains an array of [`Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.metadata?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable<code>) objects. TheGetAnswersAsync`method which is how you query your QnA Maker endpoint, will return an array of`QueryResult` objects.
4. Use the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.metadata.value?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_AI_QnA_Metadata_Value) from the Metadata object to display in your card for disambiguation. There is an example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4f978577e358d193c4a63ffdab4d10c2fc4b4874/experimental/qnamaker-support/csharp_dotnetcore/Providers/QnAMaker/ActiveLearning.cs#L132).

There is also an overview of how the QnA Maker ranking system for answers works available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/query-knowledge-base#ranker-process), currently it works as follows:

```
| Step  | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The client application sends the user query to the GenerateAnswer API |
| 2 | QnA Maker preprocesses the user query with language detection, spellers, and word breakers. |
| 3 | This preprocessing is taken to alter the user query for the best search results. |
| 4 | This altered query is sent to an Azure Cognitive Search Index, which receives the top number of results. If the correct answer isn't in these results, increase the value of top slightly. Generally, a value of 10 for top works in 90% of queries. |
| 5 | QnA Maker uses syntactic and semantic based featurization to determine the similarity between the user query and the fetched QnA results. |
| 6 | The machine-learned ranker model uses the different features, from step 5, to determine the confidence scores and the new ranking order. |
| 7 | The new results are returned to the client application in ranked order. |

Features used include but aren't limited to word-level semantics, term-level importance in a corpus, and deep learned semantic models to determine similarity and relevance between two text strings.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it deffinetly sounds helpful, thank you (both ranking system link and idea with metadata tag).

Comment: No problem @User5468622, you should post the solution that you end up going with, along any decisions that were made along the way as an answer on here, in case someone else wants to do this in the future. :-)

Comment: I will go with the strategy you've suggested. I will create special metadata property, something like user-friendly-question/disambiguation-question, which will contain user friendly question of the qna pair which can be used for active learning. But since our knowledge base has around 100 QnA pairs now and also someone can forget to add this tag to the new QnA pairs, I will use first question from QnAMakerResult as a default if metadata property user-friendly-question is missing.